# I need to create an element that hides behind its title when scrolling (I need a starting point)

Tags: javascript, css, angular, frontend, sticky

I got told to create a collapsing element (Its not the navbar) like the one you can find on the SBB website on the right side. 
[example site](https://www.sbb.ch/de/geschaeftskunden/businesstravel/sbb-businessmanager.html)

With CSS Tricks I Managed to create the Title div that stays in place.
[CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/creating-sliding-effects-using-sticky-positioning/)
But now I'm strugling to create the element with the information in it that hides behind the title with scrolling. 
I'm a junior dev and I simply have no starting point.
[Screen recording of what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj3Bb.jpg)

Here is what I got so far, now I need to make the green Box dssapear when I scroll past. Maybe with transitions?
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/elle55/pen/eaVJbN)

```
<div class="extra"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="sticky">
    sticky
  </div>
  <div class='sticky sticky-subject'>sdjfnsa</div>
</div>
<div class="extra"></div>
```

.

```
    .sticky {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  background: #f83d23;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}
  .sticky-subject{
    z-index: 0;
    top: 170px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: green;
  }

.extra,
#wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
#wrapper {
  height: auto;
}
.extra {
  height: 100px;
}
body {
  font-family: georgia;
  height: 1000px;
}
h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-height: 768px) {
  #wrapper{
    height: 2000px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for Accordian control ?  if yes take a look these examples  [Examples](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples)

Comment: @karthickj25 partially the difference being that it needs to be sticky and that it needs to open/close via scrolling

Comment: Why do you need ideas? What have you tried? Where's your approach. There's no code

Comment: @window.document Using the word Ideas was the wrong approach. But my problem stems from the fact that I don't know what keywords to use. I can only find collapsing navbars and not elements that collaps into their parent element. I was asking for pointers/Ideas since I simply don't know where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

Like This

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div style="padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px;margin-top:30px;">
  <p><b>This example demonstrates how to hide a navbar when the user starts to scroll the page.</b></p>
  <p>Scroll down this frame to see the effect!</p>
  <p>Scroll up to show the navbar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite the top part needs to stay fixed and the bottom part needs to 'transition away' like the boxes ont the right in this example https://www.sbb.ch/de/geschaeftskunden/businesstravel/sbb-businessmanager.html

Comment: you can click right click on website , and choose inspect and see the code , and JS code

Answer (score 0):

I know the feel.

It depends on what Frontend-Framework you are using. The keys/tags you are looking for is an `collapsed navbar on scroll`. If you are using the normal Bootstrap [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#nav) which is collapsing on smaller devices, then you just add the class "which lets the navbar collaps". The usual way is to check where the navbar is and if the position is changing. When the position of the navbar is changing, you adding the collapsing class.

This stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33855262/5677688) will help you to collapse the navbar.